# Mutex in Java 1.4

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to isolate function `myFunc()` from executing from several threads. I know how to solve this task with `Mutex`. Since `Java 1.4` not supports `Mutex` how to solve this task in another way?

Comment: Put maximum effort to upgrade java version...

Answer (score 1):

In Java all objects have an intrinsic lock, also called a monitor lock. This is enough to provide simple mutual exclusion but it does have limitations.

```
public final class MyClass1 {
    public synchronized void myFunc() {
        // Exclusive work here
    }
}
```

The `synchronized` keyword on the method means that the intrinsic lock of the MyClass1 object instance must be acquired before myFunc can run.

```
public static final class MyClass2 {
    private final Object mutex = new Object();
    public void myFunc() {
        synchronized (mutex) {
            // Exclusive work here
        }
        // There is no mutual exclusion here
    }
}
```

A block inside of a method can be synchronized for the scope of the block. This also allows you chose the object to acquire the lock of.

An intrinsic lock will either be acquired eventually or the thread will hang. An attempt to acquire an intrinsic lock does not timeout and cannot be interrupted.

An intrinsic lock is reentrant so you do not need to worry about a thread deadlocking with itself. Deadlocks can still happen when acquiring locks in different orders.

The synchronized keyword also ensure memory visibility of reads and write  when they both take place in a synchronised code that locks the same object.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html

You should also know that the Java memory model has changed since 1.4 so much of the current information will not be applicable.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp03304/

Comment: I prefer the final object lock over the sync method. Sync methods locking on the instance can get you in trouble when you have more than one synchronized method.